# jquery using ajax to send html tag inner and save in php

Tags: jquery, ajax

NEW

```
function save(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"save-script.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: getPageHTML()
    });
}
```

This is how I had set ip my function.

AJAX seems to be removing characters and symbols. The + and & are replaced by spaces. I have tried using the encodeURIComponent but it ends up removing everything.

This is how I am using it

```
data: encodeURIComponent(getPageHTML())
```

Am I doing this right?

OLD

I am trying to print out everything inside my `<html>` tags and send them to a php file.

Here I am getting everything inside both tags

index.html

```
function getPageHTML() {
    $("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    });
    return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

Works fine with a button to see what I am getting.

`<button onclick="console.log(getPageHTML());">Print html</button>`

I would now like to sent it to my `save-html.php` file that looks like this.

```
<?php
    echo "Here is your post:";
    print "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
    print "</pre>";
?>
```

Here is what I am trying

```
function save(){
        var query = $('getPageHTML').serialize();
        var url = 'save-html.php';
        $.post(url, query, function (response) {
         alert (response);
        });
    }
```

and the button `<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="save()"/>`

any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you missed the id/class prefix on this selector: `$('getPageHTML')`.

Comment: I am trying to call the function here. is that possible?

Comment: What is the actual output? Did you get any response? Any errors? What is the issue here

Comment: Yes. Possible. make sure that the function is called  by putting an alert or console

Comment: this is what i get...   Here is your post:<pre>Array
(
)
</pre>

Comment: which means your post values are not passed from js to php. I think the problem is in `$('getPageHTML').serialize()`

Comment: just pass a sample value in post and then check it

Comment: I tried  alert (query.value); and the response is undefined . so yes it seems that I am not getting the getPageHtml.

Comment: Yes!!! thats fine. If you solved your problem, provide an answer to your own question too. So that, it should help others

Answer (score 1):

my problem as pointed out, was that I was using `.serialize()`.
so changed it to `.html()` and this solved my problem.

looks something like this.

```
function save(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"save-html.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>"
    });
}
```